# Error in data type linq

Tags: linq

There is a request:
"Take two older (max age) children and complete their stay in kindergarten"

```
var s = db.Child.Max(e => (DateTime.Today - e.Birthday));
foreach (var n in db.Child.Where(e => (DateTime.Today - e.Birthday) == s).Take(2))
db.DeleteObject(n);
```

"Birthday" - data type => "datetime".

Error: DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type

Where did I go wrong!?

Comment: What is the type of `s`?  Unless it's a `TimeSpan` I wouldn't expect that `Where` clause to make a lot of sense...

Answer (score 2):

You overcomplicating things. The oldest children are the one... which are born first.

So

```
var oldestChildren = db.Child.OrderBy(c => c.Birthday).Take(2).ToList();

//if "complete they stay in kindergarten means delete
foreach (var child in oldestChildren)
   db.DeleteObject(child);
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT. But, what is error "System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException"?

Comment: is it on DeleteObject ? You may need to use `db.Child.DeleteObject(child)` instead

Answer (score 0):

EF do not supports arithmetic operations  with DateTime.

```
var s = db.Child.Max(e => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Today - e.Birthday));
```

[EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

pull you where statement out of the foreach statement and check your database DataType.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            List<Test> Tests = new List<Test>();
            Tests.Add(new Test(new DateTime(2014, 01, 01)));
            Tests.Add(new Test(new DateTime(2013, 01, 01)));
            Tests.Add(new Test(new DateTime(2012, 01, 01)));
            Tests.Add(new Test(new DateTime(2011, 01, 01)));
            Tests.Add(new Test(new DateTime(2010, 01, 01)));
            Tests.Add(new Test(new DateTime(2009, 01, 01)));
            Tests.Add(new Test(new DateTime(2008, 01, 01)));


            var s = Tests.Max(e => (DateTime.Today - e.Birthday));
            var d =Tests.Where(e => (DateTime.Today - e.Birthday) == s).Take(2);

    }
}

public class Test
{
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public Test(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        Birthday = dateTime;
    }
}
```

but I would think your logic is incorrect if you want the two oldest children.  This is give you oldest children if their birthdates are the same, look at

```
var oldestChildren = db.Child.OrderBy(c => c.Birthday).Take(2).ToList();
```